# The attribute for input tag"onchange" will not fire, but "onkeydown" will, why?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, js

I am creating a lightning web component.

In the **.html** I have an input tag of type text, each time the user changes the field of this input I want to run a function on the input.

```
<label class="my-label-class" for="date-of-birth-day">Day</label>
<input class="my-input-class" 
       id="date-of-birth-day" 
       name="date-of-birth-day"
       type="number" 
       onchange={validateNumberInput}></input>
```

And in the **.js** I have a simple function that should just console.log the word "hello"

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class myClassHere extends LightningElement {

    day;
    month;
    year;

    validateNumberInput(event){
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
```

When I type something into the input, validateNumberInput will not fire. However if I use onkeydown, it will fire.

Am I missing something here that would make onchange work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onchange` is only triggered when the control is out of focus. That means you have to click outside of the input field after typing something to fire the `onchange` event.

If you need event to fire immediately after every keystroke, use `onkeyup`, `onkeydown` or `onkeypress` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think I have been getting mixed up with how `onChange` works in the React framework. For my purposes I think `oninput` might actually be the best option as it will trigger with a copy paste as well.